# Best way to reuse a Runnable

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, lucene

I have a class that implements `Runnable` and am currently using an Executor as my thread pool to run tasks (indexing documents into Lucene).

```
executor.execute(new LuceneDocIndexer(doc, writer));
```

My issue is that my Runnable class creates many Lucene [`Field`](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_0_0/api/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html) objects and I would rather reuse them then create new ones every call.  What's the best way to reuse these objects ([`Field`](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_0_0/api/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html) objects are not thread safe so I cannot simple make them static) - should I create my own `ThreadFactory`?  I notice that after a while the program starts to degrade drastically and the only thing I can think of is it's GC overhead.  I am currently trying to profile the project to be sure this is even an issue - but for now lets just assume it is.

Comment: I have no prior experience in Lucene; but is it possible to use a pool of `Field` objects?

Comment: Each `Field` object is different (say 6 per document) so using one generic object pool would not work.  I also don't want to keep track of 6 pools of objects that would need to be the same size as my thread pool - so if I ever change the thread pool size I have to change the object pool size - doesn't sound very maintainable.

Comment: The GC should be optimized for dealing with small allocations that go away quickly since it's such a common use case. I'm not familiar with Lucene, but if Field objects are small enough and short-lived enough chances are they're allocated on the stack by the JIT and never even reach the GC.

Comment: WHAT do you want to reuse ? The Field objects, or the Runnables ?

Comment: You need to profile so that you can identify the problem rather than guessing that it's the large amount of Field objects causing the problem.  Otherwise you might do a whole lot of work and see no measurable improvement.  In terms of your question, have you considered if the flyweight pattern would fit?

Comment: @stevendick - yes, exactly why I mentioned it IN THE QUESTION.  Making the flyweight pattern thread-safe is often difficult.

Comment: I have indexed millions of documents using Lucene with simple code that does not reuse Field objects. It goes very smoothly. Lucene is probably not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I have decided to just use a simple Producer->Consumer model.  I pass a `BlockingQueue` to each indexer, rather then a document to index, and then have the main driver of the program add new documents to that queue.  The Indexers then feed off that [bounded] queue and reuse the `Field` objects and share the thread-safe `IndexWriter`.

I did find a place where I was possibly not calling `HttpMethod.releaseConnection()` so that could have caused my memory issues (uncertain).

Answer (score 15):

Your question asks how to reuse a Runnable, so I am going to ignore the other details adn simply answer that question.

If you are using a ThreadPoolExecutor, you can use the [ThreadPoolExecutor#afterExecute][1] method to return the Runnable object to a pool/queue of 'cached' Runnables.

[1]: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#afterExecute(java.lang.Runnable, java.lang.Throwable)

Comment: It's awesome that you're the only one who actually answered the question and didn't start talking about the circumstances instead.
+1!

Answer (score 5):

A Runnable object is reusable. It is thread object which is not.

Best way ? it is your way :-)

I think it is more a lucene question than a runnable question.

Comment: I think you have that backwards.

Comment: @Gandalf: This poster is absolutely right. It's your problem that your implementation of `Runnable` is not thread-safe. If it were, you could have definitely passed it twice ( or more ) to the executor.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to do some more benchmarking to nail down what's causing your slowdowns.

I'm willing to bet that your problem is not related to the creation of Field instances.  Field doesn't have any finalizers, and they're not designed to be pooled.